# Что означает "@Override" перед объявлением метода?

Tags: java, аннотации

Что означает "@Override" перед объявлением метода?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Аннотация `@Override` перед объявлением метода означает, что метод переопределяет объявление метода в базовом классе.

Comment: Второй ответ гораздо лучше, читайте его.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вы же понимаете, что этому вопросу 5 лет?) И судя по всему, это вообще один из первых вопросов заданных на этом сайте)

Comment: @Vartlok: отлично всё понимаю, да. Написал сообщение для будущих читателей.

Comment: @NickVolynkin тогда надо активно заплюсовать второй ответ =)

Comment: Приймите более заплюсованный ответ, он лучше!

Answer (score 136):

На самом деле аннотация `@Override` указывает, что далее мы **собираемся** переопределять метод базового класса.
При этом, если в базовом классе не окажется метода с аналогичной сигнатурой, то мы получим предупреждение компилятора о том, что хотя мы и собирались что-то переопределить, по факту этого не произошло.

На этом действие аннотации заканчивается.

Таким образом, аннотация никак не влияет на сам факт переопределения метода - при совпадении сигнатур с методом базового класса он и так будет переопределен, независимо от наличия, либо отсутствия этой аннотации. Аннотация служит лишь **для контроля** успешности действия при сборке проекта.

В случае отсутствия данной аннотации и не совпадении сигнатур (в результате ошибки) с методом, который мы собирались переопределять - случится страшное - очень трудноуловимая ошибка, когда вы думаете, что должно бы переопределяться, а по факту имеете отдельный независимый метод, который скорее всего вообще не выполняется. При этом компилятор считает, что с его точки зрения все в порядке - хотите собственный метод в классе-наследнике - нет проблем. И молчит.

Comment: Шедевральный ответ. Думаю, принять надо именно его.

Comment: @Klimenkomud вот только автор вопроса сюда не заходил уже 2,5 года :-)