# Где в этом коде совмещение, а где замещение метода distance?

Tags: java, ооп

```
class Point { 

    int х, у;

    Point(int х, int у) {    
        this.x = х;        
        this.у = у; 
    }

    double distance(int х, int у) {    
        int dx = this.x - х;    
        int dy = this.у - у:
        return Math,sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);    
    }

    double distance(Point p) {    
        return distance(p.х, p.y);    
    }

}

class  Point3D extends Point { 

    int z;

    Point3D(int х, int y, int z)   {
        super(x, y);    
        this.z = z;    
    }

    double distance(int х, int y,  int z) {    
        int dx = this.x - х;    
        int dy = this.y - y;    
        int dz = this.z -  z;    
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);    
    }

    double distance(Point3D other) {    
        return distance(other.х, other.y, other.z);    
    }

    double distance(int х, int y)  {    
        double dx = (this.x / z) - х;    
        double dy = (this.у / z) - y;    
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);    
    }

}

class Point3DDist {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(30, 40, 10);

        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);

        Point p = new Point(4, 6);

        System.out.println("p1 = " + p1.x +  ", " + p1.y + ", " + p1.z);

        System.out.println("p2 = " + p2.x +  ", " + p2.y + ", " + p2.z);

        System.out.println("p = " + p.x + ", " + p.y);

        System.out.println("p1.distance(p2) = " + p1.distance(p2));

        System.out.println("p1.distance(4, 6) = " + p1.distance(4, 6));

        System.out.println("p1.distance(p) = " + p1.distance(p));

    } 
}
```

Comment: Вы про разницу между overloading и overriding?

Comment: Да, где они в коде отображаются? Спасибо!

Comment: Необходимо внести ясность в определения - в отношении методов в Java возможны: *Override* - переопределение и *Overload* - перегрузка. При этом и совмещение и замещение тела метода (кода) возможно только при overriding-e - переопределении метода. В первом случае в переопределяемом методе необходимо вызвать оператор `super`, который сначала выполнит код базового метода, затем код переопределяемого метода. При перегрузке по факту мы имеем дело с разными методами, у них одинаковое только имя - компилятор Java никак не ассоциирует такие методы по совместному признаку.

Comment: Так же, хорошим тоном считается при переопределении метода указывать аннотацию `@Override` - это не только прилично для программиста, но и очень [полезно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/467665/177345). С.А. Сухов видимо за какие то прогулы писал свою книжку, почитайте лучше Эккеля или Шилдта.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Переопределение(overriding)` - это когда методы имеет одну сигнатуру, но разную реализацию. Возможно только при наследовании. В вашем примере это 
`Point3D.distance(int x, int y);`, потому что в его предке есть метод с такой же сигнатурой `Point.distance(int x, int y);`

`Перегрузка(overloading)` - это когда методы имеют одно имя, но разный набор параметров. В вашем примере это `Point.distance(int x, int y);`, `Point.distance(Point p);`, `Point3D.distance(int x, int y, int z);` и `Point3D.distance(Point3D other);`

Comment: Спасибо! все предельно ясно!!!

Comment: @Ya16 если ответ вам помог, не забудьте отметить его как правильный, галочка под голосами.

Comment: термины *замещение* и *совмещение* некорректны в отношении процессов *override* и *overload* и никак не отражают сути происходящего. Есть устоявшиеся термины - *переопределение* и *перегрузка*. Лучше всего не подстраиваться под неверные определения новичков, а приручать их использовать верные определения с самого начала.

Comment: @pavlofff как я понимаю, этот пример и термины взяты отсюда: http://sernam.ru/book_java.php?id=37 Основы программирования на Java: учебное пособие / С. А. Сухов. -Ульяновск: УлГТУ, 2006

Comment: @Vartlok Чтож, С.А. Сухов не прав, придумав такие термины, не посоветовавшись со старшими товарищами :)

Comment: @pavlofff ну в общем я в любом случае с вами согласен, не хотел изначально путать человека, но думаю сейчас он уже поймёт всё правильно, + ваш комментарий.