# Java. Наследование private переменных

Tags: java, наследование

Из теории мы знаем private переменные не наследуются. 
Тогда как быть с таким примером ?

```
public class A {
        private String str;

        public String getStr() {
            return str;
        }

        public void setStr(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }
    }     

    public class B extends A {
    }

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B b = new B();
            b.setStr("b");
            System.out.println(b.getStr());
        }
    }
```

Ответом будет - "b". Но ведь не наследуются private переменные! Разве не так ?

Comment: к ним нет доступа, но это не значит, что они не наследуются. Попробуйте из класса `B` получить доступ к `str` и увидите что нельзя. А сейчас все работает, т.к. к `str` обращается метод, объявленный в `A`, а не в `B`. Если переопределите в `B` метод `setStr`, тогда можно будет обратиться к `str` только через явный вызов метода родителя, иначе получите ошибку.

Comment: нет доступа и не наследуются это разные вещи

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Класс В наследуется от класса А, и, так как метод `setStr(String str)` не переопределён в классе наследнике `(В)`, то этот метод будет вызываться из класса родителя, точно так же как и метод `getStr()`, соответственно, не смотря на то что то обращение идёт к классу B, в нём не переопределены эти методы для своего внутреннего пользования и работа идёт непосредственно с родительским классом.

Переопределённые методы обычно помечаются как `@Override` сверху от самого определения.

Comment: отсутствие [аннотации @Overrride](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/467665/177345)  не является гарантией, что метод не переопредлен. Переопределение происходит при совпадении сигнатур метода-предка и метода-потомка, а не при наличии анотации.

Comment: Это понятно, для удобства чтения указывается + IDE могут сами добавлять. Полезное уточнение моего сообщения, возможно я неправильно выразился, недостаточно точно указал что значит переопределение.

Answer (score 0):

Все приватные методы наследуются sub классом по умолчанию. Метод будет автоматически вызываться и из super класса