# Не работаєт @NotNull

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

1. Для чего нужна аннотация @NotNull, я ее должен сам через рефлексию описать?
2. А @Override работает, где эта рефлексия которая его описывает?

Comment: При чём тут рефлексия? =/

Comment: Аннотация это только маркер, чтобы описать аннотацию и она что-то проверяла нужно использовать рефлексию, разве не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@NotNull это аннатоция из пакета javax.validation.
Для запуска валидации необходимо использовать валидатор, например:

```
    ValidatorFactory vf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = vf.getValidator();

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyClass>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(myClass)
```

И дальше уже просатривать полученный сет на предмет имеющихся предупреждений.

Автоматическое проведение валидации осуществаляется в некоторых фреймворках, напримр в Hibernate при персисте объектов:

```
   entityManager.persist(myClass);
```

Об аннотации @Override можете прочесть в ответе на данный вопрос [Что означает "@Override" перед объявлением метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-override-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)